# Recommended way of translating authentication errors in symfony2

Tags: authentication, internationalization, symfony

I need to display, for example, the "Bad credentials" message in another language.
So far I found that it is thrown as an exception in
`\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php`
`authenticate` function as
`throw new BadCredentialsException('Bad credentials', 0, $notFound);`

I am wondering what would be the recommended way for showing this message in another language. Just changing the string in this place seems non-optimal...
Also there are other messages that might probably be shown during authentication.

I am using the `JMSSecurityExtraBundle` and `FOSUserBundle` and I guess there could be some built in functionality to handle this...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Override login template: copy **FOSUserBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig** to **app/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig** (see [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates), [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eumgRULsR3g))
2. Add **trans** filter to **error** variable in login.html.twig (see [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates)):

   {{ error|trans }}
3. In your translate file **src/YourBundlePath/Resources/translations/messages.{locale}.yml** add:

   Bad credentials: Your error text

Comment: Great, thanks. I just needed to clear the dev cache for this to take effect.